# creating an array where every element is a list of varying lengths in R

Tags: arrays, r

I wish to create an array. Each element will be assigned to be a list, and each list will be of a different length (unknown before the script is executed). A simple example would be to let a[1] be the list q and a[2] be the list. Is there a construct that I can use, perhaps different than array, that would allow for such assignments.

```
q <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

w <- c(6,7,8)

a <- array(2)

a[1] <- q
```

Warning message:

```
 In a[1] <- q :  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: In R arrays are multidimensional data structures. An R vector or list is closer to a java/C array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want an array of lists, try:

```
a[1] <- list(q)
```

Comment: This coerces `a` into a `list`

Comment: I think both solutions produce identical results -- a vector of lists.

Comment: @senorO, rmk is correct.  Except I wouldn't necessarily call it a vector of lists, but rather a list of vectors.

Comment: What I was saying is that by doing `a <- array(2) ; a[1] <- list(q)`, you are changing `a` from an `array` to a `list`.

Comment: @SeñorO, ahhh.. gotcha.  yep, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you are likely looking for `list` and not `array` *(the latter being more akin to a multi-dimensional matrix or mathematical vector.)*

However in addition to that is the issue if indexing:

In `R` there is a major difference between `a[1] <- q` and `a[[1]] <- q`

Try the following to spot the diff:

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- q
a[[2]] <- w 
a
```

Compare with

```
a <- list()
a[1] <- q
a[2] <- w 
a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a list of vectors.

```
q <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
w <- c(6,7,8)
a <- list()

a[[1]] <- q
```

Comment: Or just `a <- list(q, w)`

Answer (score 0):

list works - thanks! it allows me to partition an array of positions into a list of lists according to some separation cutoff.

delta <- 200

pcls <- list(nrow=pctot)

v <- posvec[1]

pcind <- 0

jtest <- 0

for (j in 2:nr) {

```
dist <- posvec[j]-posvec[j-1]

if (dist <= delta) {

    v <- c(v,posvec[j])

    jtest <- 1

}

if (dist > delta) {

    if (jtest > 0) {

        pcind <- pcind + 1

        pcls[[pcind]] <- v

        v <- posvec[j]

    }

    jtest <- 0

}
```

}